# Mongoose save() not saving to the database

Tags: node.js, express

I have this endpoint on my expressjs server file

```
app.post("/subLikes", (req,res) => {
console.log('subLikes');console.log(req.body);console.log('subLikes');
let id = req.body.id;
let commentid = req.body.commentid;
let job_id = req.body.job_id;

if(req.session.login) {
    let user_id = req.session.user._id.toString();
    let user_name = req.session.user.firstname + " " + req.session.user.lastname;

    jobModel.findById(req.body.job_id).then(data => {
        data.comments.forEach(comment => {
            if(comment.comment_id == req.body.commentid) {
                let a = comment.likes.filter(com => com.id == req.body.id);

                if(a.length == 0) {
                    let sublike = {id,commentid,job_id,user_id,user_name};
                    comment.likes.push(sublike);
                    res.json({message:'added'});
                } else {
                    comment = comment.likes.filter(comm => comm == a);
                    data.save().then(data => {
                        res.json({message:'removed'});
                    }).catch(error => console.log(error))
                }
            }
        })
    }).catch(error => console.log(error))
} else {
    let user_id = "";
    let user_name = "";

    jobModel.findById(req.body.job_id).then(data => {
        console.log("data see");
        data.comments.forEach(comment => {
            if(comment.comment_id == req.body.commentid) {
                console.log("comment see");
                let a = comment.likes.filter(like => like.id == req.body.id);

                if(a.length == 0) {
                    let sublike = {id,commentid,job_id,user_id,user_name};
                    comment.likes.push(sublike);
                    console.log(comment.likes);
                    data.save().then(data => {
                        res.json({message:'added',comments:data.comments});
                    }).catch(error => console.log(error))
                } else {
                    comment.likes = comment.likes.filter(like => like == a);
                    data.save().then(data => {
                        res.json({message:'removed'});
                    }).catch(error => console.log(error))
                }
            }
        })
    }).catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

})

the code receives req.body.id, req.body.commentid and req.body.job_id from the front end and add or remove like to/from the like array of a particular comment. Now I tried to like a comment when I am not logged in, the res.json({message:'added',comments:data.comments}) is received on the front end but I check the database it's not saved. What could be the problem?

Comment: have you tried to change the parameters to `async (req, res)` and await the data.save()?